Set Builder Notation Question for proof of Heine-Borel Theorem
Self studying Real Analysis A long-Form Mathematics Textbook by Jay Cummings.
A proof of The Heine-Borel Theorem is presented. I understand the forward direction. The backward direction has some set notation in it that I cannot grasp:

Now assume that $S$ is closed and bounded. We will show that $S$
is compact. To that end, assume that $F$ is an open cover of $S$. We
will show that $F$ contains a finite subcover of $S$.  For each $x$,
define the set $$S_x = S \cap(-\infty, x)$$ and let $B=\lbrace x$: F contains a finite subcover of $S_x \rbrace $. Intuitively, $S_x$ is the set $S$ up to the point $x$, and as $x$
increases we are slowly revealing more and more of it. Since $S$ is
bounded, both $\inf(S)$ and $\sup(S)$ exist. Moreover, recall that such
a set always contains a sequence of points converging to its infimum,
and a sequence converging to its supremum. And since $S$ is also
closed, this means that those limits - $\inf(S)$ and $\sup(S)$ - must
in fact be elements of $S$.

This is a great book and works well for me. However I cannot understand what B is.
$B=\lbrace x$: F contains a finite subcover of $S_x \rbrace $
$x$ such that F contains a finite subcover of $S_x$?

$F$ is an open cover of $S$ means in particular that it is a set of subsets of $\Bbb R$. More formally, $F\subseteq \mathcal{P}(\Bbb R)$, where $\mathcal{P}(X)$ denotes the power set of a set $X$.
Given a subset $T\subseteq\Bbb R$, we say that $F$ contains a finite cover of $T$, if there exists some $n\in \Bbb N$ and elements $U_1,…,U_n\in F$ such that every element of $T$ is contained in some $U_i$. The lengthy formula for this would be
$$\phi(T)= \exists n\in \Bbb N, U_1,…, U_n \forall t\in T\exists i\in\{1,…,n\}: t\in U_i$$
The set $B$ is supposed to be formally given by
$$B=\{x \in S \mid \phi(S_x) \}$$
But it is understandable, why the author chose the informal
$$B =\{ x\in S \mid F\text{ contains a finite subcover of } S_x\}$$

Okay I think I get it. Thanks for you time

You are welcome :)
